# Trying to replace a space ' ' at a specific position in every line of a .txt file using regex

Tags: regex, excel, sublimetext

I have a text file that is tab delimited that I can import into excel. There is one problem there where I do not have a tab between 2 sets of data which should be delimited into 2 different columns when I import. I would simply like to replace the space character at position 40 with the tab character for every line in the file.

Example Data:

```
02/01   02/04   24123069033893031235753 CHESTER LAKE BUENA VIFL $86.16
```

I would like to:

```
02/01   02/04   24123069033893031235753     CHESTER LAKE BUENA VIFL $86.16
```

I have tried many different attempts using the regex to replace in Sublime text with no luck. I feel like this should be a simple solution but I have been  searching Stack Overflow for 2 hours and trying different solutions.

Comment: There's no need to use a regular expression here; simply concatenate 1) the string consisting of the first 39 characters of a line; 2) a tab character and 3) the string consisting of all but the first 40 characters of the line.

Comment: In future you may wish to wait longer before selecting an answer. Quick-draw selections can discourage other answers and imo, are disrespectful to those still working on answers. The point is there is no hurry. Many here wait at least a couple of hours before making a selection, some wait much longer, allowing then-sleeping members an opportunity to contribute solutions.

Comment: Sorry about that Cary. I am new to stack overflow and learning but that is a good point. I should have waited longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example way if the character is always the 40th character in a line:
use the regex `^(.{39})( )` with a replacement of `$1\t` and it will replace the 40th character (which has to be a space) with a tab.

Essentially the regex is just grabbing the first 39 character into the first capturing group ($1) and then the space afterwards. Then you replace that with the first capturing group and a tab to replace the space.

https://regex101.com/r/bhORsu/2

You could also get rid of the first capturing group by using a positive lookbehind instead which would enable you to only match that one character exactly. The regex would be `(?<=^(.{39}))` and the replacement would be `\t`, but I don't know for sure if sublime supports positive lookbehind.

https://regex101.com/r/bhORsu/4

Comment: Thanks!!! This worked. Both solutions worked perfectly with sublime. Much appreciated!